# Xamarin Forms Collection View Pagination

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, uicollectionview

I want to achieve pagination in xamarin forms, actually I have not done this for any mobile application so this is my first time. I am using **collection view** and **remainingItemThreshold** and the event is being triggered but the items are not being added. I think this is a good logic to go through but I think I am missing something. Thanks in advance!

```
        private async void Init()
    {
        SetViews();

        Methods.SetFlowDirection(this);

        Methods.BeforeChecking(activityIndicator, parent);

        GetOrdersApiResponse response = await OrdersPageLogic.GetOrders();

        Methods.AfterChecking(activityIndicator, parent);
        //
        // get all orders
        orders = response.Orders;
        
        toRange = orders.Count >= pagination ? pagination : orders.Count;

        // only show first 10 items
        ordersToShow = orders.GetRange(0, toRange);

        // remove fetched items
        orders.RemoveRange(0, toRange);

        ordersCollView.ItemsSource = ordersToShow;
        
        ordersCollView.RemainingItemsThreshold = 2;

        ordersCollView.RemainingItemsThresholdReached += (s, e) => ordersCollView_RemainingItemsThresholdReached(s, e);
    }

    private void ordersCollView_RemainingItemsThresholdReached(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int to = 0;

        if (orders.Count == 0)
            return;

        to = pagination >= orders.Count ? orders.Count : pagination;

        foreach(var order in orders.GetRange(0, to))
        {
            if (count == pagination)
                break;

            ordersToShow.Add(order);
            count++;
        }

        // remove fetched items
        orders.RemoveRange(0, to);
    }
```

Comment: is `ordersToShow` an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @Jason DAMN I forgot that it has to be, I defined it as a list. i'll give it a try but yes I think it willl work and  I'll get back to u

Comment: @Jason always saving my day! thank u

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @Jason it appeared that the item source (in my case ordersToShow) have to be **observable collection** not **list**